# Hints on how to get Intellij Scala Plugin to stop at breakpoints

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, breakpoints

The screenshot of the following tiny scala script shows four breakpoints set.

```
object WC {
  val code = """import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
// This class performs the map operation, translating raw input into the key-value
class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper[Object,Text,Text,IntWritable] {
"""

  def sloc(str: String): Int = {
    val x: List[String] = str.split("\\n").map(_.trim).toList.filter { line =>
      line.length!=0 && !line.startsWith("import ") && !line.startsWith("/*")  && !line.startsWith("//") && !line.equals("{") && !line.equals("}") }
    println(x.mkString("\n"))
    x.size
  }
}

 println (WC.sloc(WC.code))
```

[image]
Here are the peculiarities:

- only the very last breakpoint - on the "println (WC.sloc(WC.code))" - is actually respected. The others are ignored
- However, I can step through the other three lines in the debugger

I am wondering if others have discovered any "pattern" to how to get the scala debugger to respect the breakpoints. OK we know that the scala plugin is buggy - it is here a matter of trying to get the "most" out of what we have.

I am using the latest IJ ULtimate 12.1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the debugger to work properly IJ unfortunately needs a CLASS to be available - not just the Object.  This may have been fixed in 13.